# Show that $c\mid(ax+by)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Freshman here.

Let $a,b,c,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and let $c\neq 0$. Assume $c\mid a$ and $c\mid b$.

Show that $c\mid (ax+by)$.

**My approach**

Since $c\mid a$, $c\mid b$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $c\mid ax$ and $c\mid by$.

And then $c\mid(ax+by)$.

**Questions:**

- Is this rigourous enough?
- How do I know for sure that c is also a divisor in the sum?
- Any constructive criticism welcome

Comment: What's your justification for stating that $c|ax$ and $c|by$ implies that $c|(ax+by)|$?

Comment: It looks good, I don't think that's any reason to be incorrect. Just a simple property of divisibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what has already been proven in your class, you might need to justify your (correct) implications. Besides that, everything is OK, good job.

To answer you question: $c\mid ax, c\mid by \implies ax=cq, by=ck \implies ax+by=cq+ck=c(q+k)$

Comment: What would you say that I generally need to justify besides the last step that you prove in your answer? I haven't had my first lecture yet :)

Comment: Mostly that, maybe a short comment on why $a,x \in \Bbb Z \wedge c|a \implies c|ax$, after that you've proved all the tools you've used. Although these properties are pretty basic, so after your first lecture, I think, they'll be treated as obvious.